# Match on shortest distance with aggregation function min() in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have Station nodes, and Neighborhood nodes. They both have a location attribute which is of type `point` of the spatial data type.

I need to create a relationship between the nodes (a Station belongs to the closest neighborhood). Therefore, I should only get one row per station. However, my query gives back all combinations as a result.

```
MATCH (n:Neighborhood),(s:Station)
WITH n, s, min(distance(n.centerLocation, s.point)) AS shortest
WHERE distance(n.centerLocation, s.point) = shortest
RETURN s.stationId, n.name, shortest
ORDER BY s.stationId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Your [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) is using both `n` and `s` as the grouping keys, instead of just `s`.

This should work for you:

```
MATCH (n:Neighborhood), (s:Station)
WITH n, s, distance(n.centerLocation, s.point) AS dist
ORDER BY dist
RETURN s.stationId, COLLECT(n)[0].name AS name, COLLECT(dist)[0] AS shortest
ORDER BY s.stationId
```

Note that this query is going to be slow (and possibly run out of memory) if you have a lot of neighborhoods and stations, since it will have to evaluate every possible combination of neighborhood and station.

As a potential workaround to that, you could create a relatively small number of `Region` nodes and relate every `Station` and `Neighborhood` to a particular Region. Once that is done, you can reduce the number of combinations that need to be evaluated. For example:

```
MATCH (n:Neighborhood)-[:IN_REGION]->()<-[:IN_REGION]-(s:Station)
WITH n, s, distance(n.centerLocation, s.point) AS dist
ORDER BY dist
RETURN s.stationId, COLLECT(n)[0].name AS name, COLLECT(dist)[0] AS shortest
ORDER BY s.stationId
```

For better results, you could also put a `Station` or `Neighborhood` into multiple regions if its distances to those regions' centerpoints only differ by some threshold.

Comment: I'm currently working with a small subset. The full dataset will have 13000 possibilities. If the number is too big, is there a better way to approach this? Or should I write a program that creates a query that can match each station.

Comment: The region approach isn't really applicable in my scenario because the difference between region and neighborhood is too small. In a bigger case, it would be great.

One last question if you don't mind. When i add a CREATE clause, it still creates relationships for every possibility. I don't see how I can solve this.

Comment: Open a new question with full details.

Comment: Follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421117/create-relationship-after-matching-with-aggregate-and-multiple-order-by-clauses