# Create relationship after matching with aggregate and multiple order by clauses

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Follow up question on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419391/match-on-shortest-distance-with-aggregation-function-min-in-cypher/58420040?noredirect=1#comment103183653_58420040)

I now need to create the relationship between a station and a neighborhood (LOCATED_IN). The first query successfully returns only 1 row per station (1 combination). The second query where I want to create the relationship, creates too much relationships.

```
MATCH (n:Neighborhood),(s:Station)
WITH n, s, distance(n.centerLocation, s.point) AS dist
ORDER BY dist
RETURN s.stationId, COLLECT(n)[0].name AS name, COLLECT(dist)[0] AS shortest
ORDER BY s.stationId
```

**Query 2:**

```
MATCH (n:Neighborhood),(s:Station)
WITH n, s, distance(n.centerLocation, s.point) AS dist
ORDER BY dist
CREATE (s)-[r:LOCATED_IN]->(nbh)
RETURN s.stationId, COLLECT(n)[0] AS nbh, COLLECT(dist)[0] AS shortest
ORDER BY s.stationId
```

**Query 3:**

```
MATCH (n:Neighborhood),(s:Station)
WITH n, s, distance(n.centerLocation, s.point) AS dist
ORDER BY dist
CREATE (s)-[r:LOCATED_IN]->(n)
RETURN s.stationId, COLLECT(n)[0] AS nbh, COLLECT(dist)[0] AS shortest
ORDER BY s.stationId
```

**After query 2:**
Stations (blue nodes) are connected to multiple nodes that do not represent neighborhood nodes. They only have an ID.
[image: Query 2]

**After query 3:**
Stations (blue nodes) are connected to multiple neighborhoods nodes. It should only be one neighborhood per station.
[image: Query 3]

**How should I write my query to have 1 neighborhood per station?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 2 is flawed because the `CREATE` is using an unbound `nbh` variable.

For Query 3, you need to create a relationship from each station to just the single nearest neighborhood. For example:

```
MATCH (n:Neighborhood), (s:Station)
WITH n, s, distance(n.centerLocation, s.point) AS dist
ORDER BY dist
WITH s, COLLECT(dist)[0] AS shortest, COLLECT(n)[0] AS nbh
CREATE (s)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(nbh)
RETURN s.stationId, nbh, shortest
ORDER BY s.stationId
```

Comment: This gives me the same result (Query 3, Image 2)

Comment: Oops. Fixed it.